# how to do group by and get the row count and assign it to columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to group by code and get row count and assign it to columns in dataframe

```
df_input:
ID   Code
1    2345
2    2345
3    2345
4    1111
5    1111
6    3456
7    3456
8    3456
9    3456

The code I have here is:
column_names = ["FileType", "Code", "RowCount"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
df["Code","RowCount"]=df_input.groupby("Code").size()
df["FileType"]="Filetype1"
```

I am getting output like this

```
FileType    Code    RowCount    ('Code', 'RowCount')
Filetype1                                3
Filetype1                                2
Filetype1                                4
```

I am expecting the output :

```
FileType    Code    RowCount    
Filetype1   2345        3                     
Filetype1   1111        2                     
Filetype1   3456        4
```

I know we can do this by reset.index() but not able to get it right .

Can anyone please help me what am i missing here?

Comment: 1) There is no `FileType` in your sample data. 2) If there was, then `df.groupby(['FileType'])['Code'].value_counts().reset_index(name='RowCount')`, or `df.groupby(['FileType', 'Code']).size().reset_index(name='RowCount')`.

Comment: filetype will be hardcoded value in new data frame. it wont be in input data

Comment: Then just `df = df_input.groupby("Code").size().reset_index(name='RowCount')`, then hardcode the file type?

Answer (score 2):

Like that

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[2345,2345,2345,1111,1111, 3456,3456,3456,3456],columns=["Code"])

df["RowCount"] = 1

df = df.groupby("Code", as_index=False, sort=True).agg({"Code":"first","RowCount":"sum"})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Code  RowCount
0  1111         2
1  2345         3
2  3456         4
```